# I have set Meta tags for fb share button on my page, but it is not working fine for all ids

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Opening a page using querystring and trying to share that page using share button and setting meta tags and it is working for some postid which I am getting from querystring in asp.net

Below is the link of page 
**http://efinancedoctor.in/AddComments.aspx?PostId=6**- for this it is giving warnings like

> Inferred Property  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property  The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

and for 
**http://efinancedoctor.in/AddComments.aspx?PostId=10** - it is working good

Answer (score 2):

The PostId10 link was scraped *after* the PostId6 link, and includes an image tag which is causing the problem. Re-scraping this today gives the same error that PostId6 has.

The existing scrape of both links shows it can't find any meta tags, so that is what is causing the problem.

PodtId10 also gives this error from the old scraped information:

> og:image could not be downloaded or is too small
>   og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://efinancedoctor.in/images/logo-right.gif' will be used instead. Consult http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler for more troubleshooting tips.

The problem is that the GIF is 180x203 pixels, but facebook's minimum size is 200x200 px.

Answer (score 0):

For the PostId10, you also have an error for the og:image property, because the content isn't a url.

It should be : `<meta property="og:image" content="http://efinancedoctor.in/images/logo-right.gif" />`

For the PostId6, here is the code that Facebook see : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fefinancedoctor.in%2FAddComments.aspx%3FPostId%3D6

And I don't see meta tags for Facebook in the `<head></head>`. So if they are not there, Facebook doesn't know what to display.